# What is causing the invalid syntax error in this very simple Python program?

Tags: python, syntax-error

Just starting out learning Python and programming in general. Following along with a video on LIL and everything has worked fine up until now. I'm trying to access the first 3 rows of a specified series with the following code. I keep getting a syntax error where it highlights my colon. What am I doing wrong? It looks exactly like the text in the video.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/filename.xlsx")

print(df['Visit  '],[1:3])
```

Comment: What's the syntax error you're getting

Comment: @Ashok It literally just says "invalid syntax" in a little popup box, then when I click OK it highlights the colon in between 1:3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(df['Visit  '],[1:3])
```

The placement of the comma means you are passing two separate items to `print()`:

```
df['Visit  ']
[1:3]
```

The problem is the second item.  `[1:3]` is not valid by itself.